# Deleted default web parts templates?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

just a quick question.

For some reason i cannot see the default web parts when trying to adding a web part to a page. I can only see the custom one i created, did i delete them ? Is there a way to restore this without reinstalling the server ?

Thanks

Comment: "sharepoint central administration" would be the place to restore from a backup but it doesnt include a back up from the installation date. 

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Site Action > Site Settings > Webpart Gallery

If you dont see all the OOTB webparts then yes you have deleted them by mistake.

Only option to recover is to create a new site collection and copy files of its Webpart Gallery and upload in your Webpart Gallery